# personaje is not associated to pelicula en sequelize

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy intentando relacionar, la tabla de personajes y de pelicula. Cuando realizo un get para mostrar las peliculas y los personajes relacionados me muestra el error
.
SequelizeEagerLoadingError: personaje is not associated to pelicula!
La primary key de pelicula esta en la columna de titulo

```
Pelicula.associate = models=>{
    Pelicula.belongsToMany(models.Personaje)
}
```

La primary key de personaje esta en nombre

```
Personaje.associate = models => {
    Personaje.belongsToMany(models.Pelicula)
}
```

GET API

```
  router.get('/movies',async(req,res)=>{
       
        const peliculas = await Pelicula.findAll({
            attributes:['imagen','titulo','fechaCreacion','personaje'] ,
            include:[{model:Personaje}] 
        }).then(peliculas=>{
            return res.status(200).json({
                peliculas
            });
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log("ERROR! "+error);
        })
        
    })
```

Comment: Necesitas poner la asociación también en `Películas` usando `Películas.hasMany(models.Personaje)`. o `Películas.hasOne(models.Personaje)` dependiendo como hayas definido la relación.

Comment: Buenas, la asociacion se la puse en ambos modelos.

Comment: Si pero en este caso, como es muchos a muchos, debes establecer la relación usando una tabla intermedia.  Checa https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la [documentación oficial](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html):

> La manera más simple de definir una relación de muchos a muchos es:
>
> ```
> User.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: 'User_Profiles' });
> Profile.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'User_Profiles' });
> ```

Aplicado a tu código:

```
Pelicula.associate = models => {
    Pelicula.belongsToMany(models.Personaje, { through: 'Pelicula_Personajes' })
}
```

y

```
Personaje.associate = models => {
    Personaje.belongsToMany(models.Pelicula, { through: 'Pelicula_Personajes' })
}
```

Donde `Pelicula_Personajes` es el nombre de la tabla intermedia que establece las relaciones entre las dos entidades.

---

Si la relación es *una película tiene muchos personajes* tu código quedaría:

```
Pelicula.associate = models=>{
    Pelicula.hasMany(models.Personaje)
}
```

```
Personaje.associate = models => {
    Personaje.belongsTo(models.Pelicula)
}
```

Para que te devuelva todas las películas con sus respectivos personajes:

```
const peliculas = Pelicula.findAll({ include: Personaje });
        .then(peliculas=>{
            return res.status(200).json({
                peliculas
            });
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log("ERROR! "+error);
        })
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo estaba viendo, pero esta tabla intermedia, no muestra todos los campos de cada tabla?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con los campos de cada tabla? Si tienes una relación de muchos a muchos necesariamente debes tener una tabla intermedia en tu base de datos, y si estás haciendo que sequelize te genere la base de datos entonces automaticamente te genererá la tabla intermedia. ¿Probaste corriendo la consulta justo como la tienes cambiando las relaciones como te dije?

Comment: Me refiero a que la tabla Personajes tiene varias columnas(nombre,edad,historia) y la tabla pelicula tiene otras columnas(genero, titulo). Y al llamar al api, pueda devolverme todas las columnas de ambas tablas,

Comment: Una pregunta para entendernos bien: ¿Cómo es la relación entre Personajes y Películas? *Una película tiene muchos personajes* o  *Muchos personajes tienen muchas películas y muchas películas tienen muchos personajes*. Si solamente tienes dos tablas (Peliculas y Personajes) checa la edición que agregué. Creo que estás confundiendo las relaciones

Comment: La relacion seria muchos personajes tienen muchas peliculas. Intente de la forma que me comentas, pero me muestra el mensaje de: EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: personaje is not associated to pelicula!

Comment: Prueba la segunda vía que te acabo de adjuntar. Dices que tu relación es de muchos a muchos pero sospecho que en realidad es de uno a muchos.

Comment: Lo modifique segun lo que me comentas, pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: personaje is not associated to pelicula! .

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134998/discussion-between-jaime-menendez-and-alan-galvan).